# Textual Entailment on large data corpus

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I'm working on textual entailment recently and I wanted to know the current research projects pertaining to Textual entailment on large datasets.

I have read research papers for the same and wanted to explore if there are any possibility of applying data augmentation to make the limited dataset robust or even applying Hierarchical attention mechanism?

Your valuable thoughts and references are very much appreciable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could have a look at https://nlpprogress.com/english/semantic_textual_similarity.html for state of the art models

Transfer Learning and pre-trained Language Models is a big theme since last year so you can have a look at https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-transformers instead of data augmentation